# Change margin on right side

Tags: margins

I'm trying to figure out how to get a bigger margin on the right side of a page. I have found this snippet: 
    `\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{.875in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{.875in}`
This does about what I'm looking for, however on every other page, the increased margin is on the left. How can I change this so that it's always on the right

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i) to help you we need example of small complete document, (ii) see the package `geometry`. settings of page layout with it is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a *local* change of the margins, you can load the `changepage` package with

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{leftmargin}{rightmargin}
   ......
\end{adjustwidth}
```

The starred version `\begin{adjustwidth*}... \end{adjustwidth*}` swaps the values between even and odd pages.

Another solution consists in using these commands of `geometry`:

```
\newgeometry{parameters for the new layout}
   .......
\restoregeometry
```

One difference with the other solution is that these commands start a new page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the geometry package?

```
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.875in]{geometry}
```